# How can i call Jquery AJAX external URl in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

Can jquery ajax code call a webservice from another domain name or another website?
Below is the code i amm using,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://developers.google.com/public/oauth2/1/files",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': headerDATA,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            alert(AJAX);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Failure");
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

How to solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it can

Your problem is due to the absence of double quotes in the url. url field in the ajax should be string value. Try the code below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://developers.google.com/public/oauth2/1/files",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': headerDATA,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            alert(data.items[i]);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Failure");
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

Comment: No, `error: function (e) {
        alert("Failure");
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }` this error

Comment: add `console.log(e)` in the error block, and go through the console for errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169134/discussion-between-mahendra-and-aneesh-r-s).

Comment: Hi @aneesh, i got the solution

Comment: i have one more doubt.

Comment: go on.If its a question, please add it as new post